# how to run multirobot simulation

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm new to ROS, I did a couple of tutorials so i understand the basics. I want to make a simulation with 2 robots where one is navigating to the goal position and the other one is following him. I found turtlebot_stage package which seems quite appropriate for the navigation task but i have difficulties adding 2nd robot.

So my questions are:
is there a way to run multiple robots with this package and if so how?
is there a better option for this task?

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258580/how-to-run-multirobot-simulation/) by [hornacekz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29931/hornacekz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hopefully you have found the answer and solved your problem. In case you are still struggling, please do pay attention to the naming of both the robots. Same names would mean that one robot will be dumped by ROS while starting other. Different robot name will allow you to start both of them. Once done the navigation stack should also be started under the same name. You can use ROS namespace feature for this purpose. Last but not the least, in the transformation published for the whole thing you will need to have a single transform something like "map" connecting both the robots to your world. So map should be the root node in tf and both robot's base should be connected to it, tf_veiw can help you visualize this.

---

Originally posted by [Usman Arif](https://answers.ros.org/users/22287/usman-arif/) with karma: 58 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0